# Include static file in JSP with variable filename on WebSphere 6

Tags: java, jsp, websphere, websphere-6

I'm struggling with including a static file into my JSPs on **Websphere 6.0.2.17**. I tried this:

```
<% final String MY_DIR = ResourceBundle.getBundle("mybundle").getString("props.pages.wcm"); %>
<% final String page = ResourceBundle.getBundle("mybundle").getString("page"); %>
<% final String inc = MY_DIR + "/" + bonus; %>
<%@include file="<%= inc %>"%>
```

The path is /wcm/some/other/dir/page and I can happily print that out with `out.write(inc)`. Unfortunatly the `include` (and the `jsp:include`) isn't including the file at all. There is no error message, but the content isn't included... The file is accessible via the browser though.

Do I have to create a full JSP for this to work? I just need a HTML file.

**Update**

Because there will be more pages to be included sooner or later I decided to create a custom taglib for this case. That way I can capsulate the functionality and set the base directory for my static content in a property file.

Comment: Could it be a problem with the file sitting outside of the application directory and outside the application server directories at all? I try to load from another directory which path is made available inside my JSPs...

Comment: Does this static file located in your project, or outside the project? If this HTML file resides in your project, then the static include should work just fine.

Comment: It is outside the project, in another directory that is far across the filesystem, but readable for the webserver user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using RequestDispatcher.include():

```
<%
RequestDispatcher r = request.getRequestDispatcher(inc);
r.include(request, response);
%>
```

This is just like the include directive, except whatever page you are including will be processed every time (if it's a JSP or servlet).  The include directive only processes the page once when the JSP file that the directive resides in is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I tried through `jsp:include` and the file got included perfectly.

Keep in mind that you have to provide the relative path and not the absolute path.

Comment: Did you tried this with a file *outside* of your application directory?